# How to change character encoding to UTF-8 in Grails 3.3.9?

Tags: grails, utf-8, character-encoding

My grails application doesn't render german Umlaute correctly (ä, ö, ü). I didn't find any information on how to change the character encoding in Grails 3.3.9.

I have already tried putting the following into the application.yml:

```
grails:
    converters:
            encoding: UTF-8
```

But that didn't change that if I put Umlaute in my Java / Groovy files, they don't get displayed properly. Is there anything else I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

try add

```
grails:
    views:
        gsp:
            encoding: UTF-8
```

Comment: I already have that, but my gsp files are actually displaying everything correctly. The problem is that if I put Umlaute in my Java / Groovy files, they won't get rendered and even printed to the console properly.